# Jenkins trigger build every 8 commits only - How to do this?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I have a declarative pipeline I made. I'm trying to make Jenkins trigger build after every 8 commits only. 
I'm new to Jenkins, how do I trigger a build based on commit number?

Comment: May I ask what's the use case?

Comment: You could trigger it everytime but only run the pipeline every 8th time - this would be possible in Jenkinsfile.

Comment: This is part of an assignment. The reasoning is to "reduce" the load on our server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided each commit triggers a build:

```
pipeline
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Check 8 commits') {
            steps {
                def build_num = env.BUILD_NUMBER as int
                if (build_num % 8 != 0) {
                    error "This is not 8th commit"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of just failing the build, one could also set the result to `NOT_BUILT`, which would make it easier to distinguish from actual build failures: `script { currentBuild.result = hudson.model.Result.NOT_BUILT }`